# In Birt, Can I pass one dataset's results as input to another dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

This may not be a Birt question and may be solved with SQL itself. Please find my query below.

I have a complex query, 6 small queries joined with unions and intersects. All the small queries have a common inner query. Now writing it as a part of query will run this inner query 6 times, which I want to avoid. I want to pass the values of this inner query directly to the Main query.

The Main Query template is given below.

```
Select A_ID id from A where A.TYPE in (select Type from My_Type_List where Type_id=?)
UNION
Select B_ID id from B where B.TYPE in (select Type from MY_TYPE_LIST where Type_id=?)
UNION
Select C_ID id from C where C.TYPE in (select Type from MY_TYPE_LIST where Type_id=?)
```

Is there a way to optimize this query or to pass the values of the inner query as a parameter to Main Dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to run the first query and collect the results in a global JavaScript object.

You can then reuse the elements elsewhere using JavaScript.

The only alternative is to use an inner join in the second query.